# Facet Block : only 10 items are shown

Tags: search

Using Search_api, search_api_db and facet_api.

Ive created a view display using 'Facet Block'.

Ive set the facet field to the one I want to use. The facet configuration of this field has no listing limits.

ive set the view setting's 'pagination' to display all items.

When I look at the rendered block, it only shows 10 items.

Does anyone ever face this kind of problem ?

Is there an hard-coded limit ?

Comment: Using hte debug template setting, or preprocess_block function, I can see that the block is populated with 10 items, no more.

Comment: I don't know why but facets are limited at some point

Comment: any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually edit this limit in the search_api_views module source file.

You find this here in the commerce kickstart bundle:

/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/search_api/contrib/search_api_views/includes/display_facet_block.inc

Then you correct the limit of 10 on line 167 of **display_facet_block.inc**

`$limit = empty($this->view->query->pager->options['items_per_page']) ? 100`